# How to use RFE with xgboost Booster?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-selection, lightgbm

I'm currently using `xgb.train(...)` which returns a booster but I'd like to use RFE to select the best 100 features.  The returned booster cannot be used in RFE as it's not a sklearn estimator.  XGBClassifier is the sklearn api into the xgboost library, however, I am not able to get the same results as with the `xgb.train(...)` method (10% worse on roc-auc).  I've tried the sklearn boosters but they're not able to get similar results either.  I've also tried to wrap the `xgb.train(...)` method in a class to add sklearn estimator methods but there's just too many to change.  Is there some way to use the `xgb.train(...)` along with RFE from sklearn?

Comment: XGBoost has an sklearn wrapper already. Does that work for you? https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of problem, I created [shap-hypetune](https://github.com/cerlymarco/shap-hypetune): *a python package for simultaneous Hyperparameters Tuning and Features Selection for Gradient Boosting Models*

In your case, this enables you to perform `RFE` with `XGBClassifier` in a very simple and intuitive way:

```
from shaphypetune import BoostRFE

model = BoostRFE(XGBClassifier(), min_features_to_select=1, step=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], early_stopping_rounds=6, verbose=0)

pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

As you can see, you can use all the fitting options available in the standard XGB API, like `early_stopping_rounds` or custom metrics, to customize the training process.

You can use **shap-hypetune** also to compute parameter tuning (also simultaneously with feature selection) or to compute feature selection with `RFE` or `Boruta` using **SHAP** feature importance. Full example available [here](https://github.com/cerlymarco/shap-hypetune/tree/main/notebooks)